# Interpretation of STL plot

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to time series. Please help me in interpreting below mentioned STL plot.

[image]

As per my understanding of STL plot, plot says there is no Trend but seasonality. Please let me know whether my understanding is correct or not. STL plot has bars on the right hand side. What is the meaning of that bars on the right side of the plot

Comment: Yes, it's a little counter-intuitive, the smaller the bar on the right the greater the variability associated with the component.

Comment: @user2974951 can you please help me in understanding the concept behind those bars?

Comment: You should take a look at some documentation for the exact procedure, but basically the whole variation is computed for the time series, then it's decomposed into it's components, then the variation of every component is estimated, and at the end each component's variation is expressed as the ratio of the total variation.